# Yii image resizing on the fly?

Tags: image, yii, resize

How to use phpthumb in yii to make it resizing image on the fly?

ex: `<img src ='phpthumb.php?src=example.jpg&w=200&h=100'/>`

I cant make it works in yii.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/419/image-resize-on-the-fly/

Answer (score 0):

I resize my images with this snippet.

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    $image = new Imagick('image.jpg');
    $image->adaptiveResizeImage(1024,768);
    echo $image;
?>
```

You can try, for example, with this one

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    $image = new Imagick($_GET['src']);
    $image->adaptiveResizeImage(1024,768);
    echo $image;
?>
```